# Model that references many of itself?

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

Given the following class, how would I allow a node to have a many to many relationship with other nodes (such as `parent_node` and `child_nodes`)?

```
class Node
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :text, String
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can children have more than one parent?  If not, many/belongs_to should work fine:

```
class Node
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :text, String
  key :parent_node_id, ObjectId

  belongs_to :parent_node, :class_name => 'Node'
  many :child_nodes, :foreign_key => :parent_node_id, :class_name => 'Node'
end
```

If nodes can have multiple parents...

```
class Node
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :text, String
  key :parent_node_ids, Array, :typecast => 'ObjectId'

  many :parent_nodes, :in => :parent_node_ids, :class_name => 'Node'

  # inverse of many :in is still forthcoming in MM
  def child_nodes
    Node.where(:parent_node_ids => self.id)
  end
end

# ... or store an array of child_node_ids instead ...

class Node
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :text, String
  key :child_node_ids, Array, :typecast => 'ObjectId'

  many :child_nodes, :in => :child_node_ids, :class_name => 'Node'

  # inverse of many :in is still forthcoming in MM
  def parent_nodes
    Node.where(:child_node_ids => self.id)
  end
end
```

Is that what you're looking for?